# Installing the numbers module in Python

Tags: installation, python

I recently encountered an error in a program due to the line 'import numbers' stating that the module numbers has not been installed. I am aware of how to install for example a package by running pip in the command line but am not sure what command to type to install a module or what package the numbers module is part of.

Comment: There is a numbers package on pypi. Is that the one you want? https://pypi.org/project/numbers/

Comment: "or what package the numbers module is part of." Did you try asking the author of the script, or the person or organization that provided it to you?

Answer (score 0):

> I am aware of how to install a package by running `pip`, but am not sure what command to type to install a module.

Regarding terminology:

- A Python **module** is an individual Python file containing Python definitions and statements.
- A Python **package** is a collection of Python modules containing an additional `__init__.py` file.

So there are no additional steps to "install a module". The `import` statement can be used to import modules from a given package into a script.

> I am not aware of what package the `numbers` module is part of.

Unfortunately, you haven't detailed anything regarding your script, so its unlikely anyone here can offer more than guesses. You may want to consider editing your question and adding some additional details regarding your script and the platform (OS) you are using.